# Oracle PL/SQL How to get time in Paris?

Tags: oracle, plsql

What is the best way to always get the right time in Europe/Paris (including summer/winter times) ?

So far, I'm using the following query :

```
select FROM_TZ(CAST(Sysdate AS TIMESTAMP), 'Europe/Paris') from dual
```

It was working nicely in a previous server. However, we have changed our database server and now we are getting a difference of one hour.

Is there any way to get always the correct time in Paris ?

Thanks.

Comment: Is the time the same on both servers?

Comment: No, there is a difference of one hour. Isn't automatically adjusted ?

Comment: If the server time is treated by Oracle as UTC time and it is different on each server then of course it won't result in the same time. Other possibility will be date, if one server is inside summer time and the other is not

Comment: you can try to configure NTP service for all of the Oracle servers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`SYSDATE` is returned in the time zone of database server's operating system. When you run `FROM_TZ(CAST(Sysdate AS TIMESTAMP), 'Europe/Paris')` then you "attach" time zone `Europe/Paris` to SYSDATE.

So, `FROM_TZ(CAST(Sysdate AS TIMESTAMP), 'Europe/Paris')` is only correct if the time zone of database server's operating system is `Europe/Paris`.

Try `SYSTIMESTAMP AT TIME ZONE 'Europe/Paris'` then result is always correct because `SYSTIMESTAMP` returns a `TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE` value and time zones are properly converted.